# XML node values where xml data has colon syntax

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to move data from an xml column to a normalized database table and I can't figure out how to read the xml nodes.  Can someone provide some help. I haven't seen any examples where the colon : syntax is used.

```
    DECLARE @xmldata XML;

SET @xmldata='<storename:results xmlns:storename="http://www.storename.com/soap/rpc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.storename.com/soap/rpc results.xsd ">
  <storename:testCode>11</storename:testCode>
  <storename:drawNumber>2286</storename:drawNumber>
  <storename:resultset>
    <storename:row>
      <storename:column name="test_code" value="11" />
      <storename:column name="draw_number" value="2286" />
      <storename:column name="draw_status" value="20" />
      <storename:column name="draw_date" value="2006-03-01 00:00:00.0" />
      <storename:column name="draw_time" value="00:00:00" />
      <storename:column name="win_number">2-14-15-16-43-48</storename:column>
    </storename:row>
  </storename:resultset>
</storename:results>'

SELECT @xmldata
SELECT  x.rec.query('./test_code').value('.','varchar(10)') AS xmlresult
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/storename/results/resultset/row/column') AS x(rec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "colon syntax" is an **XML namespace** that is part of your XML document, therefore you need to respect and use it when querying, too.

I'm not 100% sure what you really want to get from that XML - my sample code here iterates over the `<storename:column>` nodes and extracts the `Name` and `Value` attributes from them:

```
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.storename.com/soap/rpc' AS ns)
SELECT 
    ColName = rec.value('@name','varchar(50)'),
    ColValue = rec.value('@value','varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @xmldata.nodes('/ns:results/ns:resultset/ns:row/ns:column') AS x(rec)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot!